# MSAL SSO with Microsoft Teams Tabs

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal

Hi So I'm using MSAL to authenticate my users, It's working in my browser but I want to embed my web in Microsoft teams tabs and use the SSO. If I see on the MSAL documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso I can use AcquireTokenSilent and using sid to authenticate. but I don't know why I get this error `Unhandled Rejection (ClientAuthError): Token renewal operation failed due to timeout after calling the AcquireTokenSilent`.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    var needAuth = true;
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    await microsoftTeams.getContext(async function (context) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(context));
      needAuth = false;
      const provider = {
        scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "user.read"],
        sid: context.sessionId,
        extraQueryParameters: { domain_hint: 'organizations' }
      };
      await authProvider.acquireTokenSilent(provider);
      alert(authProvider.authenticationState);
      this.setState({ needLogin: needAuth });
    })
  }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Am I missing something after AcquireTokenSilent?

Comment: Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/ydogandjiev/taskmeow/blob/afd7c9a2318094d00533ba271a81db0e64096fa6/src/services/msal.auth.service.js#L47) and try to implement the code to get auth token? try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT hi after some read on the internet there is some open GitHub issue that said MSAL don't work with Microsoft teams. Because Microsoft Team using Iframed Web. Is this still true?

Comment: Teams support MSAL Auth here is the [official sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs). Could you please share the git-hub link which you are referring?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT - that sample is for using MSAL as a package in a node backend. Is it possible to use MSAL as a package in the Front end if I am embedding a SPA app inside teams? It is possible for normal SPA apps but the docs I can find still seem to push to using ADAL in this instance